# Favicon not showing in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm new to Wordpress Development and trying to learn some customization. My favicon is not currently showing although I've added a folder named `assets` which contains an image `favicon.ico` in my theme directory.

This is my `header.php`:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <!-- Favicon-->
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
      Some content goes header
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A link to a favicon usually doesn't belong in a theme, unless it's a theme used only once for a specific website. After all it should represent that website, not the theme installed. For that purpose simply put it in your web root.

Did you use Developer Tools / Network to inspect the request for the favicon?

Comment: Please clarify the path for assets folder. Should it be directly inside the themes folder or it should be placed like "themes/our-theme/assets"?

Comment: An "assets" folder should be inside your theme folder or any subfolder, of course. According to your code snippet you put in in your themes stylesheet folder. A favicon however usually doesn't belong there. But that's debatable...

Comment: Again: Please use Developer Tools / Network to inspect the network request. If you don't know how: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/ (similar on other browsers). It's the #1 tool for web developers.